# Proxy IP for Scrapy framework

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy, tor

I am developing a web crawling project using **Python** and **Scrapy** framework. It crawls approax **10k web pages** from e-commerce shopping websites. whole project is working fine but before moving the code from testing server into production server i want choose a better proxy ip provider service, so that i dont have to worry about my **IP Blocking** or Denied access of websites to my spiders .

Until now i am using middleware in Scrapy to manually rotate ip from free proxy ip list available of various websites [like this](http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/)

Now i am confused about the options i should chosse

1. Buy **premium proxy list** from http://www.ninjasproxy.com/ or http://hidemyass.com/
2. Use **[TOR](http://www.torproject.org.in/)**
3. Use **VPN Service** like http://www.hotspotshield.com/
4. Any Option better than above three

Comment: Checkout this https://github.com/nabinkhadka/scrapy-rotating-free-proxies

Answer (score 10):

Here are the options I'm currently using (depending on my needs):

- [proxymesh.com](http://proxymesh.com) - reasonable prices for smaller projects. Never had any issues with the service as it works out of the box with scrapy (I'm not affiliated with them)
- a self-build script that starts several EC2 micro instances on Amazon. I then SSH into the machines and create a SOCKS proxy connection, those connections are then piped through [delegated](http://www.delegate.org) to create normal http proxies which are usable with scrapy. The http proxies can either be loadbalanced with something like haproxy or you build yourself a custom middleware that rotates proxies

The latter solution is what currently works best for me and pushes around 20-30GB per day of traffic without any problems.

Comment: does Amazon allow changing public IPs often? Didn't find any info on that... I'd like to spin up 20 instances and rotate their public IPs often (probably every minute) using APIs

Comment: @herrherr could you share more on how to implement your second option. any guides for us to lookup on. much appreciated. thanks  :)

Answer (score 7):

[Crawlera](http://scrapinghub.com/crawlera/) is built specifically for web crawling projects. For example, it implements smart algorithms to avoid getting banned and it is used to crawl very large and high profile websites.

*Disclaimer: I work for the mother company [Scrapinghub](http://scrapinghub.com), who also are core developers of Scrapy.*

Comment: It’s just too expensive for a single developer. Their plans start at $99/month.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a paid service please consider just using a scrapy library that will automate rotating proxies for you: https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/scrapy-rotating-proxies

You can have a look for a full tutorial on how to automate it here: https://tinyendian.com/articles/how-to-scrape-the-web-and-not-get-caught

Keep in mind, that when connecting through a proxy always imposes a performance penalty, but **10K** web pages that you mentioned is still well within your reach.

Comment: If you don't want to always go and check for available free proxies, you can use this library https://github.com/nabinkhadka/scrapy-rotating-free-proxies. While running a spider, this library will automatically fetch fresh and newly available proxies.